# Sometime happens that creating XML document runs at the same time by same method in 5 seconds Timer interval

Tags: c#

I use `Timer` to call a method each interval.

But when is interval too low, e.g. 5 seconds, there is a problem with creating / loading documents.

Example:

1. After 5 seconds, `Timer` calls a method
2. After another 5 seconds, `Timer` calls the same method

This method gets data and tries to create a xml document.

But sometime happens that creating xml document runs at the same time.

I create document with `DateTime` name, so it returns an error, that another process already manipulating with the file.

Can I do something like this:

```
public void after(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    // gets data
    // check if the previous calling this method already created the file
    // if yes, create
    // if no, wait e.g. 5 seconds?
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest temporarly disabling the `Timer`.

```
public void after(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    var timer = source as Timer;
    timer.Stop();

    //do your stuff

    timer.Start();
}
```

As a side note, since you are creating an XML document you have to make sure to call `Dispose` to release all handles to the files.

It is recommended to wrap every disposable object in a `using` statement.

For exmaple:

```
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml"))
{

}
```

Comment: Doesn't it restart interval as well? I mean, it would wait next 5 seconds again, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JohnDoe - the idea is to halt the timer temporarly and let the document creation happen, and when the document is createad, restart the timer which again will trigger in 5 seconds, without start/stop the timer will run every 5 seconds not taking into account how long the document creation needed, for example if the document creation takes 3-5 seconds the timer could easily overlap

Answer (score 0):

Use `Task`. This way every time you call the method it will run its own process and the rest of the code can freely execute. This way multiple XML-s can be created simultaneously.

`Task.Run(GenerateXML)` will call `GenerateXML` method and run the method, while the rest of code can execute without waiting the method to end. If you need to wait the result of `GenerateXML` method, make it `async` by putting the keyword `async` in its definition and putting the keyword `await` where you need the result.

Comment: What if two tasks will run and generate XML file with datetime as name. The second task returns an error.

Comment: I suppose date and time in file name consist of year, month, day, hour and minute. Could you add seconds, too? This way name will be different every time.